# Do I require a visa and yellow fever certificate for a transit in Luanda?

Tags: visas, transit, angola

I am travelling to Lisbon from Cape Town via Luanda, with a two hour layover, in May.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Will you be changing planes?